# How do I print the x and y values of the houses that I am generating?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I managed to generate a 1000 by 1000 grid of houses, but it prints out a 1000 by 1000 grid of null. I want that grid to print out a 1000 by 1000 grid of the x and y values of each house. However, using my getx() and gety() methods only returns a NullPointerException. I am not sure what is wrong with my getx() and gety() methods.

```
public class House {
    static String[] houseletters = Stream.of("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J").toArray(String[]::new); 
    static String[] houseletters1 = Stream.of("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "FF", "GG", "II", "JJ").toArray(String[]::new);
    private double streetnum;
    private double avnum;
    private String houseletter = "";
    private double length = 100;
    private double width = 100;
    private double x;
    private double y;
    private double units = 1;

    public House(double streetnum, double avnum, String houseletter, double length, double width, double x, double y, double units) {
        this.streetnum = streetnum;
        this.avnum = avnum;
        this.houseletter = houseletter;
        this.length = length;
        this.width = width;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.units = units;
    }
    public double getStreetNum() {
        return streetnum;
    }
    public double getAvNum() {
        return avnum;
    }
    public String getHL() {
        return houseletter;
    }
    public double getLength() {
        return length;
    }
    public double getWidth() {
        return width;
    }
    public double getX(double x) {
        return x;
    }
    public double getY(double y) {
        return y;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.houseletter;
    } 
}
```

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        House[][] houses = new House[250][100];
        Homerville homerville = new Homerville(2000000, 250, 50, 200, 1000, 24960,"Bart Complex", "Lisa Complex", "Distribution Center", 1, 300, 500);
        Point[][] graph = new Point[1000][1000];
         /*for (int i = 0; i < graph.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < graph.length;  j++) {
                graph[i][j] = new Point(i ,j);
            }
        }
        */
        printhouses(houses);

    }
    public static void printhouses(House[][] h) {
        for (int i = 0; i < h.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < h[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(h[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post more complete code, such as where `houses` is declared and what dimensions it has?

Comment: houses is declared before the for loop: House[] houses = new House[250][100]; 250 stands for number of streets, 100 stands for number of avenues. houseletters and houseletters1 are to designate which side of a block the house is on. 1 block = the length between avenues(1000 ft, or 10 houses across[avenues go vertically]), and it is the length between streets(200 ft, or 2 houses up[streets go horizontally]).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure wether the **i** or the **j** variable represents your y value but you can use the modulo operator to differentiate between even/odd numbers.

```
if (j % 2 == 1) {
  //odd
  houses[i][j] = new House(i, j, houseletters[j], 100, 100, i, j, 1);
} else {
  //even
  houses[i][j] = new House(i, j, houseletters1[j], 100, 100, i, j, 1);
}
```

The modulo operator returns the remainder after a division. If the remainder after a division by 2 equals 1 it's always an odd number.

Comment: For clarity, j is the y value.

Comment: @DavidHuang Did this answer your question?  If so, please accept the answer.

Comment: I managed to fix the problem with a method that prints the houses. Even so, thanks for the help anyways Mytharael.

Answer (score 0):

I used a separate method called printhouses in order to solve the problem:

```
public static void printhouses(House[][] h) {
    for (int i = 0; i < h.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < h[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(h[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

It's just that it prints out the houses as null. I am trying to use the getX() and the getY() methods to return the x and y values of the generated houses, but it gives my a NullPointerException.